# Showing all posts from a Twitter user

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Using Twitter's API is it possible to write an application to show all the posts from a particular user when you don't know the Twitter password for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the posts/tweets are not protected, yes. You need the Twitter user_id or screen_name.

Check [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) API